How to pass dynamically generated value in to the setAttribute() method in Javascript?
I am dynamically generating input fields in a form element.
Now, for each new input element, which is created on every enter keypress event, I want to set a new "name" attribute using the setAttribute() method. But I want to assign the value to the name attribute dynamically and not hard code it. For ex. newelement.setAttribute("name", a_new_generated_value).
How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance for any help.
I tried this:
function newitem() {
  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkbox.setAttribute("name", "checkbox" + newtaskcount);
  var newtask = document.createElement("input");
  newtask.setAttribute("type", "text");
  newtask.setAttribute("name", "task" + newtaskcount);
  return { checkbox, newtask };
}

In the above callback function, the 'newtaskcount' is being generated in some other function.
I was expecting below objects:
newtask1 {
"checkbox1" : "checked";
"task1" : "abc"
}
newtask2 {
"checkbox2" : "checked";
"task2" : "xyz"
}
And so on..

"abc", "xyz", "newtask1", "newtask2": nothing in your code produces that.

You're correct but you need to create the elements and name them dynamically using the newtaskcount variable
like this
function newitem() {
  var newtaskcount = /* generate newtaskcount */;
  
  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkbox.setAttribute("name", "checkbox" + newtaskcount);
  checkbox.checked = true; // Set the checkbox as checked
  
  var newtask = document.createElement("input");
  newtask.setAttribute("type", "text");
  newtask.setAttribute("name", "task" + newtaskcount);
  newtask.value = /* set the value for newtask */;
  
  return { checkbox, newtask };
}

you have to replace /* generate newtaskcount */ and /* set the value for newtask */ with your actual logic for generating newtaskcount and setting the value for newtask this code will create a new checkbox.
Thanks
